# Android Geofencing and data communication doesn't not working because of battery optimalization

Tags: android, android-geofence, android-doze

I'm working on a project that uses geofencing. When user enters the geofence area a webservice call occour. After 3 days if the user doesn't start the application the system optimizes it by disable geofencing and/or network communication. 
I've tried android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission that worked fine, but Google rejected the new version of the app for violating policy. Can you give me some advice what should I do to avoid battery optimalization (or to Google accept the REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS).
Thanks

Comment: How many geofences are there ? Currently I am working with 12 regions and calling webservice at every entry . And there is no any battery optimization alert .Disconnect your google api client in onStop() .So it will disconnect geofencing in background .And also set geofence expiration hours .

Comment: @GevariaPurva Thanks for the hints. Meanwhile we figured out that the user's samsung smart manager caused the problem. Currently we are testing a workaround alarm that restarts application services if service killed by samsung.